# Add 23% to results from database query

Tags: php

I have a module made for prestashop that lists all specific prices.

The problem is that all prices are displayed without tax (23% in my country) as that is how they are stored in database.

I'm having hard time trying to figure out how to add that 23% tax when they are listed from database.

Here is the module code responsible for listing prices:

```
   $query = 'SELECT a.id_product, a.id_specific_price, a.price, a.reduction, a.reduction_type, p.reference, pl.name product_name, a.id_product_attribute, cl.name country_name, gl.name group_name, cu.name currency, c.email, c.company, a.from, a.to
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price` a
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p ON (p.id_product = a.id_product)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl on (pl.id_product = p.id_product AND pl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'currency cu ON (cu.id_currency = a.id_currency)
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang cl ON (cl.id_country = a.id_country AND cl.id_lang='.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'group_lang gl ON (gl.id_group = a.id_group AND gl.id_lang='.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer c ON (c.id_customer = a.id_customer)
    WHERE '.$where.' ORDER BY '.pSQL($orderBy).' '.pSQL($orderWay);

    if ($sp = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query)) {
        $i=0;
        foreach ($sp as $row) {
            $product = new Product($row['id_product'], false, $this->context->language->id, $this->context->shop->id);

            $attribute_resume = '--';
            if ($row['id_product_attribute'] != 0) {                    
                $attributes_resume = $product->getAttributesResume($this->context->language->id);
                foreach ($attributes_resume as $ar) {
                    if ($ar['id_product_attribute'] == $row['id_product_attribute'])
                        $attribute_resume = $ar['attribute_designation'];
                }
            }

            $attribute_resume = array('attribute_resume' => $attribute_resume);

            $sp[$i] = array_merge($sp[$i], $attribute_resume);
            $i++;
        }
```

Any ideas how I can add 23% to "a.price" ?

Comment: Multiply it by `1.23`.

Comment: you mean directly on sql query? Already tried "SELECT (a.price*1.23)" but It is not working.

Comment: Tired to do this like this:$query = 'SELECT a.id_product, a.id_specific_price, (a.price*1.23), a.reduction, a.reduction_type, p.reference, pl.name product_name, a.id_product_attribute, cl.name country_name, gl.name group_name, cu.name currency, c.email, c.company, a.from, a.to
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price` a

Comment: You probably need to do `(a.price * 1.23) as price`.

Comment: is `a.price` a INT? Maybe you must cast the column for the output.

Comment: It works now. That was so simple :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Matt Note that the `$sp` array is modified directly inside the loop. I suspect it is used later.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```
foreach ($sp as $row) {
    $row['price'] *= 1.23;
    $product = new Product($row['id_product'], false, $this->context->language->id, $this->context->shop->id);

    $attribute_resume = '--';
```